# Fast, Simple Programmer's Editor

Tags: performance, text-editor

Do any of you have any good links that you could share with me? I am looking for a FAST programmers editor that can open a file containing over 100, 000 lines of code really fast? i'm currently using notepad atm and its taking a good 8 seconds to open a file that is 29000 lines long :(

i would prefer something that is just like notepad.

and yes, i have tried everything that i've found on google and they all either have splash screens, or they are just too slow. i don't want to wait 8 seconds just to add a line or two. or just to check what number the last array is etc...

Comment: A single file with 100,000 lines of code?  °O°

Comment: windows - programmer's notepad, linux - gedit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

check out

[Programmer's notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/)

Answer (score 16):

Have you had a look at [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm).

I use this editor extensively and have been very impressed thus far.

Answer (score 9):

You could always try vi / vim

Comment: As much as I like vim, I'm pretty sure it fails the "must be just like notepad" requirement.

Comment: And it fails "simple." I'll use vim for the rest of my life, but I would never call it simple.

Comment: +1 for vi, once you are used to vi/vim you dont look or any other editor.

Comment: Learning curve is steep but completely worth it after the first week. I never looked back.

Comment: And you must like pink if you use the standard configuration :-S

Comment: Are you insane? yes vim rocks, but it's the *wrong* answer to this question

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)? I just tried it with 100,000 line file where each line contained 'x' * 80, and it only took about a second.

Personally I use [jed](http://www.jedsoft.org/jed/), which is a lightweight emacs clone, but it's probably not to everyone's taste. (In particular, it doesn't really feel like a Windows application - it doesn't have the normal keyboard shortcuts etc. Once you're used to it, it's very quick though...)

Comment: thanks @Jon, sublime's doin pretty well. just installed it and opened a 1k-line file and it opened within a sec or two :D. as for jed, i think i'd kinda miss all the cute little windows icons after a while hehehehe :D

Comment: +1 I'm jed fan too. (However, emacs is already very fast with today's computers)

Answer (score 4):

[Textpad](http://textpad.com/) is what I've used for years. It's cheap, light-weight, yet very functional.

It does have a splash by default, however, that can be disabled in the options.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran a test of the [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) programmer's editor and it loaded a *100,000* line C/C++ file in less than a second.

Answer (score 2):

[Cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/). It's Vim, but with sane keyboard bindings.

Answer (score 1):

TextMate if you use Mac

Comment: Huge files of the nature that OP is talking about are *not* TextMate's strong suit.

Comment: I agree with Ben, i use Textmate all the time but Vi for large file manipulation as TM gags on them.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering why no one hasn't mentioned SciTE yet... its one of the best code editors, with source code coloring support (don't know if that's the correct term for it), and lots other features...

you can also try Notepad2, such as good replacement for notepad itself, extending it to be good enough as a code/simple programmer's editor...

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioned [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) yet?

I use it on the PC i'm on now without trouble (and the *beast* has 256Megs of RAM..)

Comment: and it opens a large file in no time?  (Without asking if you are really sure? ;-))

Comment: it all depends on  your .emacs file.  Is Vim really that much faster?

Answer (score 0):

In the linux world GEdit and Kate fits most needs.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ has code coloring for almost every language.

Dreamweaver is great to use purely as a text editor/FTP tool if you're doing web stuff.